# Did Jayadratha attend Draupadi swayamvar?

Tags: mahabharata, draupadi

Jayadratha has a key role at two different timings in Mahabharata: the abduction of Draupadi, death of Abhimanyu.

Did he attend Draupadi swayamvar? If yes, then did he participate in the competition?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Jayadratha attended Draupadi swayamvar:

> Bhagiratha, Vrihatkshatra, **Jayadratha the son of Sindhu**, Vrihadratha, Valhika, the mighty charioteer Srutayu, Uluka, Kaitava, Chitrangada and Suvangada, the highly intelligent Vatsaraja, the king of Kosala, Sisupala and the powerful Jarasandha, these and many other great kings--all Kshatriyas celebrated throughout the world--have come, O blessed one, for thee. ~ [Mahaabhaarata: Aadi Parva:
> Swayamvara Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01189.htm)